# Is is possible to use Outlook with an Exchange server that has limited publicly accessible resources?

Tags: mac-osx, exchange, outlook, microsoft-office

Does anyone know if it is possible to get outlook (partially) working with an exchange service with only makes Webmail and ActiveSync publicly accessible?

Thanks,

Sean W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. Outlook uses RPC over HTTP(s) for remote access. This requires a separate configuration on the Exchange server, its not part of OWA or ActiveSync. I don't think there are any full mail clients that work with Outlook Web Access or ActiveSync.

I do seem to remember a taskbar app that would notify you of new mail that it saw in OWA, but it wasn't a client, just a notifier.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: Oh well. It would just be nice not no need to fire up a VM with IE to get any decent functionality out of my school mail when I'm off-campus. Heck, my android phone with ActiveSync has a better feature set than OWA light.

Comment: Probably not helpful to you, but Exchange 2010 has a new version of OWA, called Outlook Web App. It actually doesn't suck in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Also, it sounds like your Exchange policies are pretty locked down, but it might be possible to set up a forwarding address within OWA. You could forward all your mail to Gmail, and configure Gmail to send as your school account. This would still show your Gmail address if the SMTP servers are not available, but might be better than "IE via VM"